Problema con Codeium en VSCode Insiders Mac
buenas! Alguien que utilice Codeium en VsCode Insiders? Porque hace tiempo lo tengo y siempre me anduvo genial. Pero hace un rato no quiere arrancar, desinstalé la extensión, el vsCode Insiders, borré la carpeta de extensions y vovlí a instalar mi perfil, etc… Y nada
Sin embargo, en el vscode normal si me funciona
Agradezco su ayuda desde ya :)

Estoy usando MacOs *


No voy a votar la pregunta como fuera de tema, pero si estás usando una versión "Insiders" y una extensión no funciona, es muy posible que sea debido a un bug en el último build del IDE. Puedes reportarlo o buscar si alguien más lo ha reportado en su proyecto (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/) o usar la versión estable del IDE

Hola Pablo, no te preocupes. Luego borro esta pregunta asi no perjudica por off-topic.
Tengo entendido que vscode ya no tiene mantenimiento por parte de microsoft. He buscado y no parece tener versiones nuevas últimamente. Si sabes de algo te agradezco el dato. Saludos
